# Как добавить красные деления в QProgressBar в конкретном случае?

Tags: python, pyqt5, qpainter, paintevent, qprogressbar

Я создаю планировщик и в случае невыполнения задачи, нужно чтобы добавлялось красное деление, как на картинке:

[image: Картинка желаемого]

Answer (score 1):

Создайте класс `ProgressBar()` и переопределите в нем метод `paintEvent()`.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class ProgressBar(QProgressBar):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ProgressBar, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.setValue(0)
        
        if self.minimum() != self.maximum():
            self.timer = QTimer(self, timeout=self.onTimeout)
            self.timer.start(200)

    def onTimeout(self):
        if self.value() >= 100:
            self.timer.stop()
            self.timer.deleteLater()
            del self.timer
            return
        self.setValue(self.value() + 1)
        
    def paintEvent(self, event):
        super(ProgressBar, self).paintEvent(event)
        painter =  QStylePainter(self)
        opt = QStyleOptionProgressBar()
        if hasattr(self, 'alternative'):
            opt.alternative = self.alternative()
        self.initStyleOption(opt)
        painter.drawControl(QStyle.CE_ProgressBar, opt)

        pen = QPen(Qt.red)        
        pen.setWidth(4)
        painter.setPen(pen)        

        if self.value() == 10:
            x1 = int(self.width() / 100 * self.value()) - 1
            painter.drawLine(x1, 0, x1, 50)
        elif self.value() >= 11 and self.value() < 20:
            x1 = int(self.width() / 100 * 10) - 1
            x2 = int(self.width() / 100 * self.value()) - 1
            painter.drawLine(x1, 0, x1, 50)
            painter.drawLine(x2, 0, x2, 50)
        elif self.value() >= 20:
            x1 = int(self.width() / 100 * 10) - 1
            x2 = int(self.width() / 100 * 20) - 1
            x3 = int(self.width() / 100 * self.value()) - 1
            painter.drawLine(x1, 0, x1, 50)
            painter.drawLine(x2, 0, x2, 50)
            painter.drawLine(x3, 0, x3, 50)
            

class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        progressBar = ProgressBar(self, minimum=0, maximum=100)
        progressBar.setMinimumHeight(50)
        progressBar.setStyleSheet('text-align: center;')
        
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(progressBar)
                        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Window()
    w.resize(700, 200)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @Arsenka102rus что не так?